# Convert SQL query with a group by into an MDX script

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, dimensional-modeling

I need to create a measure on ssas using MDX to count employee number but I really don't have any idea how to convert an sql script to MDX, it's really complicated.

What I want is a measure that look like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Employee_Number]
AS (count([Collaborateur].[Matricule]) , 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

This is my sql code:

```
SELECT a.Affectation,a.code_agence
(
SELECT COUNT(b.MATRICULE) 
FROM [dbo].[ODS_HR_AFFECTATION] b 
WHERE 
 a.[CODE_AFFECTATION] = b.CODE_AFFECTATION and
 b.[DATE_FIN] = '2050-01-01' 
 ) AS employee_count
  FROM [dbo].[ODS_HR_AFFECTATION] a
```

*Result*

```
AFFECTATION        CODE_AGENCE   employee_count

Agence Megrine     1012          9
Agence Centrale    1000          9
Agence Bardo       1032          8
Agence hellel      1064          5
Agence Saloul      1061          5
Agence Ville       1079          5
Agence Aazira      1055          5
Agence batb bhar   1054          5
Agence Hammam      1093          5
Agence Midoun      1100          3
Agence May         1121          3
AGENCE KIT EDDAIER 1046          3
Agence Beb         1108          3
Agence Metouia     1120          3
Agence Mourouj 6   1128          3
Agence Metlaoui    1122          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. If i understand your problem correctly, you want to group by Affectation and code_agence and count the distinct MATRICULE for '2050-01-01'. For this purpose you want to create a measure, that will help you count the MATRICULE for any date or other grouping. Based on this understanding here is how you can solve it.

In your fact table you should have column, which contains the MATRICULEID. Now in your SSAS project you should create a Distinct count Measure on this column. Now other dimesnions like date and ODS_HR_AFFECTATION are connected to your fact, so what ever value you select for them the new measure will report the distinct count of MATRICULE for that cube space.

The query will be like.(Plz note this is just a sample, in your cube the name of the objects will be diffrent)

```
select [measures].[DistinctMATRICULE] on 0,

([DimODS_HR_AFFECTATION].[Affectation].[Affectation],
[DimODS_HR_AFFECTATION].[code_agence].[code_agence]) on 1 
from [yourcube]
where 
[Dimdate].[DATE_FIN].[2050-01-01]
```

Comment: I would like to understand the reason for down voting?

Comment: Cancelled out the negative, unsure why someone did that. I also had an idiot doing it to some of my answers recently

Comment: @whytheq Thanks man . Did you note you go an upvote for one of those answers.

Comment: It was -1 so I upvoted to make it 0. I did not down vote it as it is marked as the answer. I only down vote misleading information. I do not know who downvoted

Comment: @whytheq what i meant was I saw one of your correct answers, being downvoted. I was surprised why it was down voted. So I upvoted your answer to support your efforts.

Comment: i don't know but your answer really helped me thanks @moazrub

Comment: @msadekoussama you are welcome. You may consider up voting any answers that are helpful.